# How to get the Instagram picture or video URL directly from copy or share URL?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, instagram

I want to make an Android app which download the images from Instagram using the copy URL.
I got stuck in the first step itself
Can anyone help me in getting image or video URL from the copy link??
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Without using any API we can get the JSON file of a post by simply adding the below string at the end of the post URL.

```
?__a=1
```

Example: Post link

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/B-xoLq7h6xS
```

JSON link

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/B-xoLq7h6xS/?__a=1
```